# JsPDF: Uncaught ReferenceError: adler32cs non è definita

Tags: javascript, jquery, jspdf

Good evening,
in my application I used the jsPDF to export the data in adobe pdf format , specifically I need to export a table and in the context I used the following code:

```
// This, in a function in part
var doc = new jsPDF();
    var specialElementHandlers = {
        '#editor': function (element, renderer) {
            return true;
        }
    };
$('#pdf' + NomeMezzo).click(function () {
        var table = tableToJson($('#TblStr' + 0 + NomeMezzo).get(0))
        var doc = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'a4', true);
        doc.cellInitialize();
        $.each(table, function (i, row) {
            console.debug(row);
            $.each(row, function (j, cell) {
                doc.cell(10, 50, 120, 50, cell, i);  
            })
        }) 
        doc.save();
    });    

function tableToJson(table) {
    var data = [];    
    // first row needs to be headers
    var headers = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < table.rows[0].cells.length; i++) {
        headers[i] = table.rows[0].cells[i].innerHTML.toLowerCase().replace(/ /gi, '');
    }

    // go through cells
    for (var i = 0; i < table.rows.length; i++) {
        var tableRow = table.rows[i];
        var rowData = {};    
        for (var j = 0; j < tableRow.cells.length; j++) {
         rowData[headers[j]] = tableRow.cells[j].innerHTML;
         }
    data.push(rowData);
    }
  return data;
}
```

And at the beginning , the import of three fil js :

```
<script src="assets/jspdf.js"> </ script>
<script src="assets/jspdf.plugin.cell.js"> </ script>
<script src="assets/FileSaver.js"> </ script>
```

In the execution of this code returns me the **error: Uncaught ReferenceError : adler32cs is not defined .**
you can import the table in pdf ?

Answer (score 0):

I met the same issue and I solved mine by adding below to the head. Seems only adding jspdf.js and plugin js files is not enough sometimes:

`<script src="../libs/Deflate/adler32cs.js"></script>`

Answer (score 0):

You have to use one of the *dist* files which includes everything ready for production, either `jspdf.debug.js` or `jspdf.min.js` Pick one of them from https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF/tree/master/dist